# Lookup item in JArray by name?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JArray:

`JArray properties = capability["Properties"`];

containing this JSON:

```
[{
    "Name": "HeatingData",
    "Value": {
        "HeatingSeasonActive": false,
        "SystemSupplyLineCalculatedSetpoint": 0.0,
        "CalculatedDemandHeat": 6.87,
        "DesiredGearForHeating": 0.0,
        "SelectedHeatCurveSystemSupplyLine": 30.0,
        "HeatingSeasonIntegralValue": -16.0,
        "OutdoorTemperature": 14.72,
        "HeatingSeasonStopTemperature": 17.0
    }
}]
```

Ideally I would like to lookup an item in the JArray by name like this:

```
var heatingData = properties["HeatingData"]
```

But, that is invalid syntax.

What is the most elegant way to lookup the item in the JArray by name?

Comment: What is your `capability` object?

Comment: I assume you're using Newtonsoft.Json here, and not `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Try `properties.OfType<JObject>().Where( o => (String)o["Name"] == "HeatingData" ).Single()["Value"]`

Comment: @Dai Your code works fine, but I was hoping for some cleaner code. I don't understand why JArray didn't implement an indexer by name.

Comment: Is it JSON.NET?

Comment: `var heatingData = properties.SelectTokens("$[?(@.Name=='HeatingData')]");` Look at [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Comment: HeatingData is not name ,  it is a value. And your sample or your question doesn't make any sense. You have to decide if you looking for a   property name  by value, or property value by name.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Not sure what you mean by HeatingData is not a name. I want to lookup the value by the name "HeatingData". Looks like I'm using Nettonsoft.Json. Is that the same as Json.NET? What difference would it make if I used another library (like System.Text.Json)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an old good c# Indexer

```
    var properties = new Properties(json);

    var heatingData = properties["HeatingData"];

public class Properties
{
    private JArray data;
    public JObject this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return (JObject)data.Where(o => (String)o["Name"] == name)
                                .Single()["Value"];
        }
    }
    public Properties(string json)
    {
        data = JArray.Parse(json);
    }
}
```

or without any fancy decorations

```
Dictionary<string, JObject> properties properties = JArray.Parse(json)
               .ToDictionary(ja => (string)ja["Name"], ja => (JObject)ja["Value"]);

var heatingData = properties["HeatingData"];
```

or you can wrap this code into indexer too